# .NET - Can I build a web app to get client CPU temperature

Tags: c#

I'm looking for ways to get client CPU temperature and other information i.e. CPU name, cores, threads... specifically for C#

Found some blogs and tutorials using libs as e.g [OpenHardwareMonitor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHardwareMonitor/) but it seems they are all window application.

That makes me wonder can I make it through the website platform?

Comment: Great, thank you. I was worrying that it needs something in background that websites cannot support.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of the [CPUID SDK](https://www.cpuid-pro.com/products-system-monitoring-kit.php) which will do what you want.  The OHM code you linked to does appear to be an app however you might be able to just go in and pull out the bits you need thus making it _headless_.   OHM appears to be using WMI so that opens it up a bit

Comment: Yes, you can. But it will be about the CPU of the server. The client is off limits.